# Cannot do a Prisma migration due to null value

Tags: prisma

I want to add a column to an table but the migration is failing:

The model:

```
model Notification {
  id               Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  movie            Movie?           @relation(fields: [movieId], references: [id])
  movieId          Int? 
  movieRating      MovieRating?     @relation(fields: [movieRatingId], references: [id])
  movieRatingId    Int? 
  user             User?            @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId           Int? 
  followedUser     User?            @relation("FollowedUser", fields: [followedUserId], references: [id])
  followedUserId   Int? 
  action           String 
  value            String?
  watched          Boolean          @default(false)
}
```

The error:

> Database error:
> ERROR: column "value" of relation "Notification" contains null values
> DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState("23502"), message: "column "value" of relation "Notification" contains null values", detail: None, hint: None, position: None, where_: None, schema: Some("public"), table: Some("Notification"), column: Some("value"), datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("tablecmds.c"), line: Some(5450), routine: Some("ATRewriteTable") }

Screengrab of the table:
[image]

I understand that if the `value` column that I want to add is required that this would show an error, but the `String?` makes it's optional right?

Answer (score 1):

Took a closer look in my migrations and I added the `value` column in 2 steps. First I added it without the optional `?` but since my local db was empty there was no issue. Then I made it optional, but on production it was the first migration (adding the value without optional) that failed.

My first migration was:
`AlterTable ALTER TABLE "Notification" ADD COLUMN     "value" TEXT NOT NULL;`

After that I created another migration:
`ALTER TABLE "Notification" ALTER COLUMN "value" DROP NOT NULL;`

So this is what caused the error.

I resolved it by rolling back the first migration:  `npx prisma migrate resolve --rolled-back "20220515174738_added_value_field_to_notificaion"`

Then I changed the first migration file:
`AlterTable ALTER TABLE "Notification" ADD COLUMN     "value" TEXT;` and I removed the second migration.

Now I can deploy the migrations again :)